# comparing SSRS reports TimeProcessing between 2 servers?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am running same SSRS reports on 2 different server, server A and server B, where Server B is better in configuration than Server A.

Using Execution Log view I can see 3 different times i.e. Data Retrieval , Processing and Rendering.

Server B is giving me better results for Data Retrieval and Rendering. But Server A has better Processing time.

What part is responsible for Processing time? What to do to get better processing time?

Comment: That is primarily driven by the processor on the server.

Comment: Server A has 32 processors and Server B has 48.

Comment: Same architecture and clock speeds on both machines?

Comment: I wish I had 48 processors :)